# From Kapilavastu to Lumbini, how many minutes or hours to reach the end (Lumbini) in a chariot?

Tags: the-buddha

I was wondering how could Mahamaya (The Buddha's mother) travel from Kapilavastu to Lumbini, this quickly. It is no wonder that a pregnant Queen could travel in a chariot this far. If it occured, she would have given birth in the chariot. Interestingly some facts about Lumbini which will make you rethink history.

http://buddhalivedinsrilanka.blogspot.com/2013/04/lumbini-is-astonishing-fraud-begun-in_7.html

So how could she travel this quickly? Maybe Buddha is not an Indian. Also the Lumbini pillar looks fake? Then how does it say she traveled so quickly?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://www.rahultours.com/lumbini.php), Kapilavastu and Lumbini are 16 km apart:

> His mother queen Mayadevi, (Mahamaya), gave birth to him while
> travelling to her paternal home. Resting in **Lumbini gardens, 16 Km
> from the Kapilavastu** and emerging from a bath with her face to the
> east, she leant her right arm on a Sal tree (*Shorea robusta*), and gave
> birth to the future Buddha.

According to [this page](https://horseyhooves.com/horse-drawn-carriage-speed/), a horse carriage at walking speed can go at 2 - 4 mph or 3.2 to 6.4 km/h.

> At a trot, a horse-drawn carriage will go around 8-10 MPH. At a walk,
> a horse-drawn carriage will go about 2-4 MPH.

So 16km divided by 3.2 - 6.4 km/h is 2.5 to 5 hours. That too at walking speed. At a trot, it can be in an hour.

So why is that unbelievable?

The website you linked seems to propagate an extremist view or conspiracy theory that the Buddha was born in Sri Lanka. Such extremist views are not consistent with mainstream history and archaeology, and is even [banned on Suttacentral forums](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/extremist-views-are-banned-on-this-forum/13312).